# Is there any way to use a *.sitemap file in Sharepoint for navigation?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm working on a public-facing Publishing site.  I need to provide static navigation in the MasterPage.  I don't want it tied to my site structure.  This won't be edited very often.  I'd like to use the standard ASP.Net Navigation controls, `<asp:Menu/>` and `<asp:SiteMapDataSource/`> , which assume you have a *.sitemap file in the root.  In traditional ASP.NET, I'd end up with the following .aspx to render my nav"

```
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server"/>
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" />
```

I understand that you can point your *.sitemap file to a different location.  I'd like to point it to another file living in a list, so that users can edit the *.sitemap file if needed.

In order to transition this code to sharepoint, I've provisioned a *.sitemap file at the root of the site and at /Pages through SPDesigner (will be moved into a feature later), but I end up with an ASP menu that has a link to the Site Collection name (PU) as the parent and the web.sitemap as a child.  See image:

[alt text http://employees.claritycon.com/pwalke/blogs/nav.png](http://employees.claritycon.com/pwalke/blogs/nav.png)

I've also tried using the `<SharePoint:AspMenu/>` , but I get the same behavior.

Am I barking up the wrong tree?  Does all the redirection within SharePoint with the content database prevent me from using a *.sitemap file for navigation?

I'm also open to using a plain old xml file for navigation.

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in guessing that the built-in ASP.NET `XmlSiteMapProvider` will not work with .sitemap files stored in a SharePoint content database. I would suggest subclassing `XmlSiteMapProvider` and override how `BuildSiteMap` handles the given `siteMapFile` path to get the map data from SharePoint instead. To get you started, the source for the built-in provider is available here:  [ProviderToolkitSamples.msi](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/b/3/ab3c284b-dc9a-473d-b7e3-33bacfcc8e98/ProviderToolkitSamples.msi).